# Covariant derivative and semicolon notation

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, tensors

Let $(M,g)$ be a Riemannian manifold and $X\in\Gamma(TM)$ a vector field. We choose local coordinates $x^{i}$ on $M$. My question:

> Does the notation $X_{;ij}^{k}$ mean the components of $\nabla_{\partial_{j}}\nabla_{\partial_{i}}X$ or of the double covariant derivatice $\nabla^{2}_{\partial_{j},\partial_{i}}X:=\nabla_{\partial_{j}}\nabla_{\partial_{i}}X-\nabla_{\nabla_{\partial_{j}}\partial_{i}}X$?

I would have assumed the latter, since for example also the notation $\nabla_{j}\nabla_{i}X^{k}$ which can be found in many physics books refers to the components of $\nabla^{2}_{\partial_{j},\partial_{i}}X$. Also in Lee's book on Riemannian manifolds, it seems to be used for the latter (see Example 4.22). However, on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariant_derivative#Notation) (section "Notation"), it seems that they state that it used for the former.

Comment: Wikipedia, despite popular belief, is not a god. Individual authors may of course use their own notation, and physicists often have their own. However, the classic mathematical interpretation of the semicolon has always been to denote the covariant derivative.

Comment: @TedShifrin Thanks. I am aware that the semicolon always denotes a covariant derivative. But in the case of two covariant derivatives, it always can mean two different things, namely $\nabla_{\partial_{i}}\nabla_{\partial_{j}}X$ or $\nabla^{2}_{\partial_{i},\partial_{j}}X$, which differ by a term of the form $\nabla_{\nabla_{\partial_{i}}\partial_{j}}X$. In physics, at least as far as I know, $X_{;ij}$ usually refers to the latter, i.e. to $\nabla^{2}_{\partial_{i},\partial_{j}}X$.

Comment: In mathematics, as well, these are the components of $\nabla\nabla X$. See, for example, pp. 239-240 of Spivak, volume 2.

Comment: @TedShifrin Okay, thanks!

Comment: I doubt there is any consistency in the definition of this notation. It's a question of whether you want $X_{;ij}$ to be the components of a tensor or not. I think it might be best to require this.